Adding CSS animations such that the placeholder text appear as if it's being typed
How to add CSS animations such that the placeholder text of input field appear as if it is being typed ?
I did this but it is not showing:
.typewriter::placeholder {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em; 
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

A CSS code for adding animations to placeholder attribute of input field.

You can not animate the placeholder in CSS.
A better way would be to use an additional <span> element in a label to do so.
See this example:


.typewriter_label,
.typewriter_label input {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10rem;
}

.typewriter_label span {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.typewriter_label input:focus+span {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}
<label class="typewriter_label" for="inp">
  <input class="typewriter" type="text" name="inp" id="inp" />
  
    <span> My Placeholder </span>
</label>



Moreover, I've added pointer-events: none to the span element to make it so that clicking on it does not effect the input functionality.
I've also added a statement where on clicking the input, the span  elements hides to make it look like an actual placeholder.
